# Custom Silverlight cursor

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How can i create a custom cursor in silverlight?

Is there method other than showing\hiding canvas containing the image of the custom cursor?

Is there a professional way to do it?

Comment: This is a duplicate, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732825/silverlight-is-it-possible-to-use-custom-mouse-cursors-pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pointer
http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2010/03/16/81607.aspx